# Fetching additional data when scrolled to bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I'm trying to fetch data when screen is scrolled to bottom but the new data that needs to be fetched is not loaded. So my screen looks like this: [image]

I fetch data in initState:

```
bool isNewDocumentsLoading = false;
 bool hasMore = true;
 int page = 1;
 final controller = ScrollController();

void initState() {
   super.initState();

//Should fetch data when scrolled to bottom
controller.addListener(() {
     if (controller.position.maxScrollExtent == controller.offset) {
       fetch();
     }
   });

//Initial fetch when app is runned
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {  fetch(); }
```

and here is my fetch method:

```
   if (isNewDocumentsLoading) return;
   isNewDocumentsLoading = true;

   const limit = 4;
   Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
     var dokumenti = await _dokumentiService!.getSharedDocuments(limit, page);

     setState(() {
       page++;
       isNewDocumentsLoading = false;
       _dokumenti.addAll(dokumenti);
      
       //_dokumenti.addAll(_dokumentiRefresh);

       if (dokumenti.length < limit) {
         hasMore = false;
       }
       isLoading = false;
     });
   });
 }
```

I really don't know what am I doing wrong here and what is the problem

Comment: It looks like there is nothing wrong with the given code. It must be something else. Can you post how the UI is built?

Comment: There are packages for infinite scroll in the pub.  Those might solve this for you a bit easier.

Comment: I tried to put fetch() method to be called on element press and it works just fine, so I thing the problem is that method for recognizing when list is at end(bottom) does not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my list is inside SingleChildScrollView so i needed to put controller inside SingleChildScrollView and not the ListView, so the functions were working just fine.

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
       controller: controller,...
       
       //controller was in ListView
       ListView.builder(
                  //controller: controller,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: params.length + 1, ...
```